# backup sql server database into a flashdrive

Tags: sql-server

I've seen and read tutorials on how to back up sql server database in a C drive but I haven't seen or read how to fully back up a database into a flash drive. I tried doing it the way I back up a database in my computer or other computer that has sql server management studio but I guess it's not the same. 
When I try to do the back up in my flash drive I get this error:

> "Backup failed for Server **servername**.
>   (Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended)". It has additional information like
>   **The volume on the device `G:\Backup\mybackup is  not part of the
>   media set that is currently being processed**. Ensure that the backup
>   device are loaded with the correct media".

Is it gonna be the same way when I restore my backed up database from the flash drive to a different PC that has sql management.

This is what I've done -- (My flashdrive is in G:)

1. Created a folder in my flashdrive and named it as Backup
2. In Sql Management, I right clicked and chose task -> Backup..
3. Database: -> MyDatabase | Backup type: FULL
4. In Backup set portion, Management auto generates the Name: Mydatabase-Full Database Backup | Decription: 'blank'
5. In Destination part, Radio button Disk is enabled and selected(default) Tape is disabled. I chose the button add and I got to Select Backup Destination
6. In the Backup destination window, in the Destinations on disk, radio button file name is enabled and checked backup device is disabled. I clicked the elipsis, navigated to the G: drive and into my folder backup and input the filename.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried using BACKUP Query like this:

> For Full Backup

```
BACKUP DATABASE MyDatabase TO disk  = 'G:\Backup\MyDatabase.bak'
```

> For Differential Backup

```
BACKUP DATABASE MyDatabase TO disk  = 'G:\Backup\MyDatabase.bak' WITH DIFFERENTIAL
```

Comment: It worked! Wow I didn't know it was that easy. How about if I want to back up differential type only and at a specified time? Can you help me with that too. Thanks,

Comment: Yups. Please find my edited answer. Please vote up if it work for you.